# Completeness in finished system

Tags: infinity, goedel, axiom, inconsistency, finitism

Gödel's incompleteness theorems addresse formal axiomatic théories.

Incompleteness of arithmetic of natural numbers is an example.

My question is if a theory regarding a finite class of numbers cannot be necessarily incomplete. There are finite things so great that they seem infinite because their limits are so far that people look at them as infinite. For example, the neuronal functioning of human brain. Can I say that it's possible to axiomatize the functioning of human brain with completeness?

Comment: You should like [Priest's paraconsistent arithmetic](https://iep.utm.edu/math-inc/#H5) T(n), it is even decidable:"We imagine the standard model of arithmetic, up to an inconsistent element n = n + 1. This n is suspected to be a very, very large number... Any fact true of numbers greater than n are true of n, too, because after n, all numbers are identical to n. No facts from the consistent model are lost... there is a way, in principle, to figure out for any arithmetic sentence Φ whether or not Φ holds, just by checking all the numbers up to n. This means that T(n) is decidable."

Comment: You seem to have a basic assumption that the "neuronal functioning" of the human brain can be fully represented in (possibly very many, very large) numbers. Is that correct?

Comment: If you have a finite set of numbers, then Gödel’s incompleteness theorem does not apply. But using only a finite subset of the natural numbers does not do justice to our understanding of basic arithmetic. There is a position in the philosophy of mathematics called [ultrafinitism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultrafinitism) under which completed infinities such as the set of natural numbers are not accepted as existing. On that basis, it may be possible to avoid the incompleteness results, although it is not straightforward.

Comment: @Conifold thanks for this comment. Indeed it's what I am looking for.

Comment: @mattdm Yes I do. There is necessarily a close number of receptors and neurotransmitters and of interactions etc.. I assume that a human being is biologically finite.

Comment: @Bumble. This is precisely my issue. I have heard before some years a neuropsychiatre arguing about Gödel's theorems about brain and I wondered if it's not more retorical than philosophical thinking.

Comment: The philosopher J R Lucas and the mathematician Roger Penrose have argued that Gödel’s incompleteness theorems demonstrate that human intelligence cannot be completely described as a computer. The arguments have been discussed extensively and are widely regarded as incorrect. Stuart Hameroff is a medical doctor who has argued that microtubules in the brain can explain how consciousness arises through quantum effects. This has given rise to a theory called Orchestrated Objective Reduction, though it has not gained much acceptance in the neuroscience community.

Comment: @Bumble. I'm not going so far. Human mind, soul is of my question. I prefer to compartmentalize the questions, without any pretension when it comes to global statements. All of your comments are exciting.

Comment: @Bumble. After all you're right this is accurately the discussion I'm looking for.

Comment: @Bumble If you are interested, I feel you have all the ingredients for a valuable answer.

Comment: @kouty "Humain being is biologically finite" is a reasonable assumption but, this being _philosophy_, it's something worth noting. Here's something to consider: do you think that all analog neurological processes can be ultimately represented by _rational numbers_?

Comment: Even digital Turing machines with infinite memory cannot decide certain problem, how the finite mortal analogue human brain's neural functioning can be complete in the usual sense of effective decidability? Neurons and synapses with all their interactions may be finite, but the incoming problems represented by neural inputs are open ended and could be potentially infinite. Btw human brains are not theories, TM decidability may be better fit for your purpose...

Comment: @DoubleKnot: TM decidability and Gödelian incompleteness are two sides of the same coin. But perhaps it would be more accurate to say that they are both members of a [larger family of related results](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonal_argument).

Comment: @Kevin thx for your comment, indeed they are related via church-Turing thesis and are multi faces. It’s just felicitous and conventional to use machines as human mind metaphor, not treating it as some recursively axiomatizable theory. So are you in the camp of incomplete or complete regarding op’s finite neural mind?

Comment: @DoubleKnot: IMHO it depends on too much to have a single definitive answer: Whether neurons are significantly influenced by quantum effects, if so whether quantum effects are computable, whether it is possible to identify a fixed maximum possible size/complexity of a human brain, etc. This gets even more complicated when we acknowledge the very real interactions between the brain, the CNS, and the rest of the body. The body as a whole is surely influenced by quantum effects at some level of indirection, because humans have written academic papers about said effects. But does that matter?

Comment: @Kevin so you seem undecidable on this, and by your own two-sided equivalence I assume you're on the incomplete camp. Btw OP doesn't mention any quantum effect, and I don't believe they're considering such possibly subtle effect at all (only pure finite neurons and weights), thus I believe the classic TM's halting problem should be of interest to them...

Comment: @DoubleKnot: I am not in any camp, and I just explained to you why I think the question does not have a known-to-us answer.